# What are some good ways to customize date/time display format for different localization

Tags: java, android

Whenever I want to print out date/time format to a human readable form, IDE will recommend me to use one of the following way

```
getDateInstance()
getDateTimeInstance()
getTimeInstance()
```

However, most of the time, applying different `int style` doesn't meet my requirement. End up, I need to define my own.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormatThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal <SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        // January 2
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d");
    }
};
```

This create a trouble for me, if I want to support non-English as well. For instance, for Chinese market, I need to use separate format.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormatForChineseThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal <SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        // 1月2日
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMd日");
    }
};
```

My code will end up with the following

```
public String dateString() {
    if (chinese user) {
        return dateFormatForChineseThreadLocal.get().format(calendar.getTime());
    }
    return dateFormatThreadLocal.get().format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

This make maintenance job difficult. I was wondering, is there a better way, to customize date/time display format for different localization?

Comment: Use one of the [predefined formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html). If you can't do that, you'll probably want to use a [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) and you'll have to provide formats for all supported locales.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the time, the predefined formats doesn't meet our UI requirement.

Comment: Why don't you define the format in the strings.xml? When you read out the strings for localization you can pass that format to your date formatter and you're done?! This way you always have the maintainability because you provide all formats for those languages your app supports.

Comment: Yes. I miss out that point. Can u post the method as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you localize your app you usually create `strings.xml` files for each language your app shall support in `/src/main/res/`, where `values/` contains mostly english files and in `values-de` or `values-cn` german or chinese for instance. When you define a string resource with your format there, you can simply read that out and pass that format to your date formatter.

With this, you can simply add new languages without changing any line in your code.